# Holomorphic function in a fixed domain.

Tags: complex-analysis

Can I conclude or prove the following statement?

For every holomoprhic function $f(z)$ and a fixed domain $D$, if
$$\int_{\partial D}G(z,\overline{z})f(z)dz=0$$
then $G(z,\overline{z})$ is either zero or holomorphic in $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect. For example, let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and let $G(z,\bar{z})=z\bar{z}=|z|^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer sounds right.

Comment: @user73773: You are welcome!